# Automake ignore missing NEWS/AUTHORS/COPYING/etc. standard files

Tags: autotools, automake

Automake requires that the following "standard" files exist in the source directory of my project:

- INSTALL
- NEWS
- README
- COPYING
- AUTHORS
- ChangeLog

Obviously, none of these files are necessary for a program to build, but Automake refuses to run without them. I know about the `--add-missing` flag that will cause boilerplate files to be generated, but I would rather not have the files at all.

Is there a way to force Automake to run and ignore the missing files without generating them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `foreign` option.  Look up "strictness" in the documentation.

Comment: For clarity, one simple way to use that option is to use this in `configure.ac`: `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])`

Comment: OMG!  All this time I've just been using an `autogen.sh` script that creates dummies to shut the damn thing up, thank you! =D  I use autotools on proprietary stuff as well, and these files aren't necessarily appropriate in such projects.