# Error in automake

Tags: configure, autotools, autoconf, automake

I’ve trying to create install package for hello world sample C program.

I’ve done following staps.

autoscan

mv configure.scan configure.ac
edit configure.ac to add some macros.

aclocal

create Makefile.am within

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

Finally I did automake .

Then I got messages bellow. .

```
configure.ac:12: error: required file './compile' not found
configure.ac:12:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'compile'
configure.ac:6: error: required file './missing' not found
configure.ac:6:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'missing'
Makefile.am: error: required file './INSTALL' not found
Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'INSTALL'
Makefile.am: error: required file './NEWS' not found
Makefile.am: error: required file './README' not found
Makefile.am: error: required file './AUTHORS' not found
Makefile.am: error: required file './ChangeLog' not found
Makefile.am: error: required file './COPYING' not found
Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'COPYING'
Makefile.am: error: required file './depcomp' not found
Makefile.am:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'depcomp'
```

There aren’t any strings including `compile`, `missing` ,`NEW`, `README` or the massage said being required in Makefile.am an configure.ac files.

What should I do?

Those are information about version of some products.

CentOS release 6.4

autocomf-2.69

automake-1.14

m4-1.4

Comment: Perhaps you should have followed this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30511996/402214

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038060/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those files need to exist to conform to the standard 'automake/autoconf' set of files.

Follow the instructions it gives you: "automake --add-missing", and the missing files will be created with dummy information which you would (in a perfect world) fill in appropriately.

Try perusing the [autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html), or perhaps the [autobook](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/download.html).  See also [StackOverflow: Getting started with autotools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746135/getting-started-with-autotools).

Additionally, read the man pages, try `automake --help`, read what the utility helpfully output to assist you?

Comment: After createed those dummy files ,`automake` finished with no error.

Answer (score 13):

Probably adding `foreign` to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` macro in `configure.ac` could be helpful in this case.

Comment: how to add foreign? can you put the entire line? is it `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])` ???

Comment: Exactly. Or if `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` is already defined you can add `foreign` to list of its space-separated options. [See more](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE)

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue but `foreign` is already defined, any suggestions?